# Declaring array in Header file

Tags: c

I am trying to optimize a life game.
I need to change this code from the header file:

```
  #define MASK(col) (0x80 >> ((col) & 7))
```

(The variable "col" is a variable that will save the column, it goes from 0 to 8)

To something like this:

```
int array[9] = { 0, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
  #define MASK(col) (array[col])

(((0) & 7) = 0, ((1) & 7) = 64, ((2) & 7) = 32, ((3) & 16)...)
```

The error I am getting with this code is the following:

```
"#10010 errors encountered during linking "life.out" not built"
"#10056 "array" redefined: first defined in './lifelib.obj', redefined in 
'./life.obj'"
```

(Ps.: I've changed the name of the array to something like: "OKDPSAdiahodakDSA" and I still got the same error)

PS: This error only happens when I make this change. The entire code is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure this is C# and not just C?

Comment: ehh? header file in C#??

Comment: C not c#, sorry

Comment: Are you defining the array in the header and including twice?

Comment: @J. Calleja No =/

Comment: Your replacement `MASK` dropped the `&7` which could leave you accessing the array — by whatever name — out of bounds.  You should probably use `#define MASK(col) (array[(col)&7])` to be safe.  Also, consider the cost of memory access against the cost of computation — the original may actually be quicker on a modern CPU.

Comment: OMG THAT WAS IT!!! THANKS TO J. CALLEJA AND THIS TIP I CALCULATED EVERYTHING AND IT WORKED. IT IS SOOOO FAST NOW THANK YOUUUU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have defined the array in the header file and you have included it (directly or indirectly) in two C files:

- life.c
- lifelib.c

When the compiler generate the obj files, it sees a definition of array in each file, so it includes it in both obj files. Then, when the linker tries to generate the file it finds two duplicated arrays, one for each obj.

You should declare the variable extern in the header and define it only in one c file. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/218774).

Comment: It compiled, but I will try to work more on it, for some reason when I do:

Comment: #define MASK(col) (array[col]) 
... it does get the correct amount from array[col]

Comment: I used the "extern int array[]"; on my header and on my c file I have the following:

Comment: int array[] = {0,64,32,16,8,4,2,1, 0}

Comment: this variable is declared right aflter all my includes and externs

Comment: Sorry, but isn't array wrong? If you must  calculate (0x80 >> ((col) & 7)), then it should be {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 128}. The last 128 is strange. Are you sure there are 9 elements?

Comment: You are right! The col number goes from 0 to 78. Would it look something like this? :{128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 128.....}??

Comment: IT WORKED, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a macro.

C macros are processed by the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), which runs *before* your code compiles. So macros don't know anything about variables, which only exist as named entities during compilation. You are trying to use your `MASK` macro as if it knew the variables `array` and `col` exist, but macros don't know anything about arrays - they just do literal text substitution.

So if you do something like

int x = MASK(9);

the text

int x = array[9];

gets injected into your code. This is why you're seeing errors related to `array` even if you change the name of your array.

The easiest way to solve this would be to change the name of your array into something that you know will never be used, like `__life_mask_array`.

So you could change your code to something like:

```
int __life_mask_array[9] = { 0, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
#define MASK(col) (__life_mask_array[col])
```

Which would make a name collision less likely.

Of course, unless using a macro for this is sorely needed, you could do away with the macro altogether and just access your array. C macros tend to be more trouble than they are worth, because they do text substitution, which may cause stuff to behave unexpectedly if a macro uses a name that exists in its enclosing scope. It is a usual practice to prefix variable names used in macros with underscores in order to avoid name collisions, but there is no surefire way to guarantee you won't run into trouble.

Comment: Hm, what is calling MASK is another macro:

Comment: #define CELL_VALUE(row, col) (window[(row)][(col) >> 3] & MASK(col) ? 1 : 0)

Comment: What do you suggest me to do so I can resolve my problem?

Comment: C macros tend to be more trouble than they are worth, because they do text substitution, which may cause stuff to behave unexpectedly if a macro uses a name that exists in its enclosing scope. It is a usual practice to prefix variable names used in macros with underscores in order to avoid name collisions, but there is no surefire way to guarantee you won't run into trouble. (I added this and a suggested solution to my answer)

In the CELL_VALUE macro you could change `row` to `_row` and `col` to `_col`.

Comment: Didn't work =( But thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "I am trying to optimize a life game." Is access to your mask array without macros really one of the major bottlenecks in your program? I'm just curious.

Comment: It is the same. I did what J. Calleja told me to do, and it compiled, but it messed up some stuff.

Comment: @synchronizer It is called hundred times per main loop. It is called quite a few times

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. My code basically doubled the speed. Everyone here helped A TON. I wish I could give the "best answer" check mark to everyone.

I did was the following:
I changed this part of my 'life.h' file:

```
#define MASK(col) (0x80 >> ((col) % 8))
```

To this one:

```
  #define MASK(col) (0x80 >> ((col) & 7))
```

So I deleted/erase/commented it out the '#define MASK' and did the following:

On my 'life.c' file I created the following array:

```
int __life_mask_array[] = { 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };
```

And on my 'life.h' file had the following:

```
extern int __life_mask_array[]
#define MASK(col) (array[(col)&7])
```